# How to handle Enums from backend in frontend

Tags: java, angularjs

I use at frontend AngularJS 1.4 and at Backend Java and I have a lot of options which can be selected in frontend, e.g. the country:

```
GERMANY
FRANCE
USA
RUSSIA
```

Enums are written in upper case and I will customize this in frontend (e.g. FRANCE will become to France).

My question now would be if there is a directive or a any other support doing this in frontend.

Comment: give it a member, 'name' with values "Germany", "France", ...

Comment: You could write your own angular filter, or manually map the value in the server response.

Comment: what framework you using for your backend?

Comment: Spring (Boot, Rest, Data, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link
http://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/angularjs-create-custom-filter

It has a custom filter written which can help you out.

Here's code from link given above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="HelloApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
  <form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    </form>
    <div>{\{name|titlecase}}</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        // Code defining custom module consisting of a filter
        // The module needs to be included as dependency for using the filter, titlecase
        //
        angular.module('CustomFilterModule', [])
            .filter( 'titlecase', function() {
                return function( input ) {
                    return input.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
                }
            });
        // Angular App on this page 
        // Included CustomFilterModule as dependency
        //
        angular.module('HelloApp', [ 'CustomFilterModule'])
            .controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.name = '';
            }])
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Links can break over time. Better copy the essential parts into your answer. Link-Only answers tend to get downvoted, too.

Answer (score 0):

In view:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries | filter:filterUpperCamelCase"></select>
```

In controller:

```
   $scope.countries= [
     {name:"SPAIN"}, 
     {name:"GERMANY"}
   ];

    $scope.filterUpperCamelCase = function(element){
        element.name = element.name.toLowerCase();
        element.name = element.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.name.slice(1);
        return element;
    };
```